# An azure function app will trigger all the deployment slots?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-function-app, azure-deployment-slots

I have a function app with 2 slots (staging and prod), both of them will trigger the upload of a file in the same blob storage. My question is: if both of them will trigger the same blob storage (but act differently), the time I upload a file to that blob storage will trigger both of them or just the one that's set as primary? Thanks in advance!

Comment: good question. I could not find any information about it, but I assume the production is the one that will get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it depends on your configuration and settings when creating your slot. For instance, if you clone the settings both will trigger, else the prod will only trigger

[image: click to see screenshot]